# Javascript : Empty String Match In Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

i want to match the url with contatin `http/https` and `(www)` or without `(www)`with the help of regular expression. following is my regualr expression

```
^((https?)://)(www\\.)| ^$ +(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$
```

but in this, the empty string is not work for example : 
when i enter `http://www.google.com` is valid url but `http://google.com` is not valid.
thanks for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't search for an not existing part using `^$`. that is expecting a start of a string(row), end of the string (row).

Just make the "www" part optional:

```
^((https?)://)(www\\.)?(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$
```

another problem is, you are searching for two dots in a row:

```
^((https?)://)(www\\.)?(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$
                    ^    ^
```

I think a better pattern would be

```
^((https?)://)(www\\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*([/?].*)?$
```

Are you aware, that you are excluding a lot of valid URLS, by only allowing the characters `[a-z0-9-]`?

Comment: thanks for this , but i want to restricted `(www)` only ,in this the other character also accept like 'sss'

Comment: How to you want to know to what part of the domain the character sequence belongs? e.g. `http://www.sss.com` versus `http://sss.com`?

Comment: so @stema what i do, or please give me another regular expression , which validate all valid url.

Comment: see [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)